# Unknown web method parameter method name

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I'm building a Web Application in which I'm trying to call a WebMethod in a WebForm, I've tried every single page in google but I'm still getting nothing. This is an example of the Jquery Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Default.aspx/Return",
            data: {dato:'Hello'},
            contentType: "application/json; chartset:utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                    function (result) {
                        if (result.d) {
                            alert(result.d);
                        }
                    },
            error:
                function (XmlHttpError, error, description) {
                    $("#grdEmpleados").html(XmlHttpError.responseText);
                },
            async: true
        });
```

And this is the WebMethod in the codebehind

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Return(string dato)
    {
        return dato;
    }
```

Comment: I got the Unknown WebMethod Parameter MethodName

Comment: For starters I would never create a method that shares the same reserved word as in the language that I am coding in `Return` not a good Method name in my opinion

Comment: this is just the example... I'aint using this method actually, but no matter what, the code structure tha I'm writing is the same

Comment: What version of .Net? Is this a web application or web site?

Comment: Framework 4.0 and I think is a website, how should I note the difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a Static method this way.  Remove the "Static" reference and it will work.  Also, like someone else said - do not use that as your method name "Return".

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Return(string dato)
{
    return dato;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, on your success event the function with result is used, which is a string and u are trying to access property named d assuming result is an object.
use of only `alert(result);`
User F12 tool to debug and find your error.

Comment: I configured the webmethod response to json

Comment: it's `application/json; charset=utf-8` not chartset

Comment: I just tried what you said, but still not working... I'm hating Asp right now

Comment: try removing static keyword in your function and scriptmethod attribute for your web method. And also rename 'chartset' to 'charset'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enabled page methods in your ScriptManager element:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

and your method

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/Return") %>',
            data: {dato:'Hello'},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                    function (result) {

                            alert(result);

                    },
            error:
                function (XmlHttpError, error, description) {
                    $("#grdEmpleados").html(XmlHttpError.responseText);
                },
            async: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url = window.location.pathname + "/Return";
$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: url,
        data: {dato:'Hello'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
                function (result) {

                        alert(result.d);

                },
        error:
            function (XmlHttpError, error, description) {
                $("#grdEmpleados").html(XmlHttpError.responseText);
            },
        async: true
    });`
```

Comment: This didn't work too :/ ... but I actually think that there's something in the codebehind ... it's like the server doesn't register the webmethod or something